# Stack Overflow should allow iphone-3G tag

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, tags

Stack Overflow should allow iphone-3G tag, however since the [iphone-3gs](/questions/tagged/iphone-3gs) tag exists, it cannot be created / used.

Comment: Why would you need such hardware-specific tags? Nobody posts questions on Stack Overflow with the tags [tag:pentium-iv] or [tag:sandy-bridge]

Comment: @RobertHarvey Bugs or behaviors specific to a platform? I know some developers who would have benefitted from asking some P4-specific questions when writing their games ...

Comment: It can be created by a moderator. Which question(s) need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added your requested tag to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480618), so now it exists.  Go wild and free with it.

Note that I don't think the existence of the [iphone-3gs](/questions/tagged/iphone-3gs) tag was preventing you from creating it (assuming you have sufficient rep to create tags).  All you have to do is dismiss the tag dropdown and enter the new tag manually.

Comment: Looking at it, shouldn't it be tagged neither of the two and `iphone-4` instead, since the problem is on the latter platform?

Comment: You can make the changes. New unused tags stay in the system for 30 days.

Comment: When I tried to create the tag it told me that I could not and that I should report it on Meta :)  Hadn't ever used meta before.  I think it's because it thinks that iPhone-3GS is the plural of iPhone-3G.